# Endvalues of colorbands on a plot using Matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

How do I ensure that the colorbar has all the end values for each colorband? For example, in the current output, the greyband has no end value. I present the expected output where the greyband has the end value i.e. `5.4035`. More generally, I want a command which enables all the values of the colorbands.

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.colors import Normalize
from matplotlib import cm
import math


fig,ax = plt.subplots(1)
n=3


N=2*n*(n-1)

p=np.array([[0.0000535              , 0.000051590914956234785,
        0.00005031819159372464 , 0.00005286363831874494 ,
        0.000052227276637489866, 0.00004904546823121452 ,
        0.000049681829912469585, 0.00004650002150619425 ,
        0.00004777274486870438 , 0.00004713638318744931 ,
        0.00005095455327497972 , 0.000054035            ]])


p=p.reshape(12,1)           
P = np.array(p)
P=P.reshape(len(P),1)

Max=max(P)

Min=min(P)

a=Min
b=Max



Amax= b*math.ceil(Max)
print("Amax =",Amax)
Amin= a*math.floor(Min/a)
print("Amin =",Amin)



color = cm.get_cmap('Dark2')
norm = Normalize(vmin=Amin, vmax=Amax)
color_list = []
for i in range(len(P)):
    color_list.append(color((P[i]-Amin)/(Amax-Amin)))
    #color_list.append(color(((P[0,i])-Amin)/(Amax-Amin)))

id = 0
for j in range(0, n):
    for k in range(n-1):
        ax.hlines(200+200*(n-j-1)+5*n, 200*(k+1)+5*n, 200*(k+2)+5*n, zorder=0, colors=color_list[id])
        id += 1

    for i in range(0, n):
        rect = mpl.patches.Rectangle((200+200*i, 200+200*j), 10*n, 10*n, linewidth=1, edgecolor='black', facecolor='black')
        ax.add_patch(rect)
        if j < n-1:
            ax.vlines(200+200*i+5*n, 200*(n-1-j)+5*n, 200*(n-j)+5*n, zorder=0, colors=color_list[id])
            id += 1

cb = fig.colorbar(cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=color, norm=norm))


cb.set_ticks(np.arange(Amin, Amax, (Amax-Amin)/8).astype(float))
cb.set_label("Radius (m)")
ax.set_xlim(left = 0, right = 220*n)
ax.set_ylim(bottom = 0, top = 220*n)

plt.axis('off')

plt.show()
```

The current output is

[image]

The expected output is

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you want to add the last number (5.4e-05), you can set the Amax to just a little higher than the current number, but keeping the number of ticks at 8, it will work. If you replace the `set_ticks()` like this

```
cb.set_ticks(np.arange(Amin, Amax+0.1e-05, (Amax-Amin)/8).astype(float))
```

**Plot**

[image]